# Can a Java servlet (server side) read Firebase session (maybe from cookies or headers?)

Tags: java, firebase, flutter, google-app-engine, firebase-authentication

I have a Java servlet (running on Google App Engine Standard) talking to a Flutter client that is also logged into Firebase.  Can the Java servlet detect which user is logged in perhaps by using the admin SDK to read the HTTP headers or cookies?  I can't find such a method in the SDK though.  I guess the question is about having a Firebase client that talks both to Firebase and to other cloud services.

(I saw the servlet can talk to Firebase https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-firebase-app-engine-flexible but my question was more simply if the servlet can verify which user is signed in)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backend (it doesn't matter what it is) can't read anything directly from the client if the client doesn't pass that data along.  Typically if the client using Firebase Authentication wishes to identify the user to the server, it will pass an ID token to the backend, usually through a header.  The backend can then [use the Firebase Admin SDK to verify the ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens).  The ID token should be available in every request send to the backend where identity needs to be known.

Comment: Great thanks!  I see the Flutter client has `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().getIdToken()` so I will try sending that to the server in an HTTP header and then using the server-side Firebase Admin SDK.